# "Classroom" as an attribute or a separate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am creating an app for a school.

Still new to database design in general. Hope someone can enlighten me with this (probably) simple question.

Should I have classrooms as (i) one of the attributes of the Student model or (ii) a separate Classroom model from the Student model. (i.e. student has one classroom)?

What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

PS: I am working with rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can describe `Classroom` has a complete entity it's better to create a separate model.

You have to ask yourself some questions before creating a new model.
- Can `Classroom` have many `Student` ?
- Can `Classroom` have specific attributes ? (Name of the classroom, teacher_id)

I don't really see the cons of creating a new model to well separate attributes.